# How to use AVMetadataFormatiTunesMetadata in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, podcast

I have found virtually no information on this item: AVMetadataFormatiTunesMetadata however I think it is the key to getting specific metadata from Podcasts in iOS.

If you look to this link:
https://www.prestopod.com/how-to-add-id3-tags-to-your-podcast-mp3-file/

you will see the information I am trying to retrieve if you scroll to "The Results" > "Podcast Tags"
Specifically "feed" and "description".

Does anyone know how to this info from a Podcast file?

Just an FYI - I am able to get the metadata from the ID3 tags but many podcasts do not use them anymore in favor of the iTunes specific Description and Feed.